# Create constant variables in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Is there a way to make a constant variable in vuex? My file structure

```
store
    ├── index.js          
    ├── actions.js        
    ├── mutations.js
```

Currently in my `index.js` file, state object I have `users` array that contains

```
'users': [{
     'id': null,
     'name': null,
     'email': null,
     'details': null
 }]
```

And in my `mutation.js` file, mutation method `addUsers` I have

```
 state.users.push(
   {
      'id': null,
      'name': null,
      'email': null,
      'details': null
   }
 )
```

Is there a way to reuse this initial user property object? How do I make constants variable like this in vuex?

Comment: creating constants and variables is not dependent on the framework, but the language. since you are using javascript, you declare a constant using `const`, just like you'd declare a variable using `let` (or `var` in some rare cases).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a `consts.js` file and put all your const inside of it:

```
export const USER = {
    'id': null,
    'name': null,
    'email': null,
    'details': null
};

export const FOO = 'bar';
```

Then you can import those consts inside your `mutations.js` file by using one of these two import statements:

```
import { USER } from 'path/to/consts.js'; // just user
import * as consts from 'path/to/consts.js'; // every single const
```

And modify your mutations:

```
state.users.push(USER);
```